# Ember: accessing {{render}} options hash in controller

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

The {{render}} Handlebars helper accepts three arguments:

1. The template
2. The 'contextString' - which is essentially the model object
3. An options hash

I know that I can specify those options as follows:

```
{{render 'duty' this key1="value1" key2="value2"}}
```

And that those options can be accessed from within the render helper method with `options.hash`, however I'm not sure how to access them from within the controller that is instantiated by that call to {{render}} - in this case the DutyController.

Does anyone know how the options passed via the call to {{render}} can be accessed within the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional options hash is optional and will be passed to the view.  At the end of the helper the options are passed to the view helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, view, options);
```

I believe this is the same as if you had used the `{{view}}` helper, with the exception that the `{{render}}` helper is handling the controller and context as well:

```
{{view 'duty' key1="value1" key2="value2"}}
```

This means that the extra options are available to you on the view.  The controller will have access to the information in the model.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ibezun/1/edit)

Also check out the ember guides for the [`{{render}}` helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/)

Comment: Thank you sir! That didn't work until I actually defined the view: `App.DutyView = Ember.View.extend();`.

Comment: Yeah, having to define the view was certainly a surprise, I assumed ember would create one automatically (as per routes, controllers etc..).